# SSL negotiation failed when connecting to IMAP (Debian Bullseye)

Tags: php, imap

All of a sudden my script can't connect to the IMAP server. It started failing during the night, so I guess something has been updated on the mail server?

I can connect via my email client Thunderbird though, but not via PHP IMAP

```
Could not connect to {mail.xxx.com:143/imap/tls/novalidate-cert/user=catch-all@xxx.com}
TLS/SSL failure for mail.xxx.com: SSL negotiation failed
```

code

```
public function connect(string $folder=''){
        $this->mailbox  = '{'.$this->host.$this->flags.'/user='.$this->user.'}';
        $mailbox        = $folder ?: $this->mailbox;
        
        if($this->stream){
            if(!@imap_reopen($this->stream, $mailbox, 0, self::CONNECT_RETRIES)){
                throw new Error($this, "Could not connect to $mailbox");
            }
        }
        else{
            if(!$this->stream = @imap_open($mailbox, $this->user, $this->pass, 0, self::CONNECT_RETRIES)){
                throw new Error($this, "Could not connect to $mailbox");
            }
        }
        
        ...
        
        return $this->stream;
    }
```

## update

The IMAP server has been updated to `Debian Bullseye` which only accepts TLS1.2 or newer

The PHP version currently installed on the client is `PHP 8.1.4` and also running `Debian Bullseye`. It should be compatible and up-to-date

Have found this "bug"
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76928

Comment: First off: Check your TLS/SSL expiry date

Comment: it expires in 37 days

Comment: maybe one of CA certificates expired? try to [`sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates`](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/ca-certificates). Not sure if it possible to determine problem with provided information

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution myself. If you just change `/tls` to `/ssl` with port `993` it works

The "bug" https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76928

```
{mail.xxx.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/user=catch-all@xxx.com}
```

The solution
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78156